# Webpack can't resolve modules relative to a package's path

Tags: webpack, node-modules

Since usually all modules are store in `$root/node_modules`. As long they are there, Webpack can find and resolve the dependencies but some packages carry their own node_modules around and reference these modules with a relative path of the file to the folder (like `./myoddmodulesdependency/libs`) instead of a root modules folder (that would look like `myodddependency/lib`).

How do I configure Webpack to handle the dependencies being accessed manually as well?
I am getting this error:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/issues/742